# Get dropdown on hover menu and sub menu - bootstrap 3.3.7

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, dropdown, mousehover

How to get the dropdown menu and second level menu to open on hover. The navigation bar dropsdown on click, what change should i make it to dropdown on hover. I have taken code for navigation bar from w3schools.com. It is working fine. But i have to add a.hover or dropdown.hover in the internal css. So where do i add it.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="content-type">
        <title>UPSC Fever</title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/bootstrap.css" type="text/css"/>





        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            $(function () {

                $("#footer").load("footer.html");
                $('li.dropdown-submenu').on('click', function (event) {
                    event.stopPropagation();
                    if ($(this).hasClass('open')) {
                        $(this).removeClass('open');
                    } else {
                        $('li.dropdown-submenu').removeClass('open');
                        $(this).addClass('open');
                    }
                });
            });
        </script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/bootstrap/bootstrap-dropdown.js"></script>
        <script>
                    $(document).ready(function () {
                        $('.dropdown-toggle').dropdown()
                    });
        </script>
        <style>

            .dropdown-submenu {
                position: relative;
            }

            .dropdown-submenu > .dropdown-menu {
                top: 0;
                left: 100%;
                margin-top: -6px;
                margin-left: -1px;
                -webkit-border-radius: 0 6px 6px 6px;
                -moz-border-radius: 0 6px 6px;
                border-radius: 0 6px 6px 6px;
            }

            .dropdown-submenu .open  > .dropdown-menu {
                display: block;
            }
            .dropdown-submenu > a:after {
                display: block;
                content: " ";
                float: right;
                width: 0;
                height: 0;
                border-color: transparent;
                border-style: solid;
                border-width: 5px 0 5px 5px;
                border-left-color: #ccc;
                margin-top: 5px;
                margin-right: -10px;
            }

            .dropdown-submenu .open  > a:after {
                border-left-color: #fff;
            }

            .dropdown-submenu.pull-left {
                float: none;
            }

            .dropdown-submenu.pull-left > .dropdown-menu {
                left: -100%;
                margin-left: 10px;
                -webkit-border-radius: 6px 0 6px 6px;
                -moz-border-radius: 6px 0 6px 6px;
                border-radius: 6px 0 6px 6px;
            }

            .sidenav {
                height: 100%;
                width: 0;
                position: fixed;
                z-index: 1;
                top: 0;
                left: 0;
                background-color: #ffffff;
                overflow-x: hidden;
                transition: 0.5s;
                padding-top: 60px;  
                visibility: hidden;

            }

            .sidenav a {
                padding: 8px 8px 8px 32px;
                text-decoration: none;
                font-size: 25px;
                color: #818181;
                display: block;
                transition: 0.3s
            }

            .sidenav a:hover, .offcanvas a:focus{
                color: #3399ff;
            }

            .sidenav .closebtn {
                position: absolute;
                top: 0;
                right: 25px;
                font-size: 36px;
                margin-left: 50px;

            }

            @media screen and (max-height: 450px) {
                .sidenav {padding-top: 15px;}
                .sidenav a {font-size: 18px;}
            }
        </style>
        <script>
            function openNav() {
                document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "250px";
            }

            function closeNav() {
                document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "0";
            }
        </script>

        <style>
            /* Remove the navbar's default rounded borders and increase the bottom margin */ 
            .navbar {
                margin-bottom: 50px;
                border-radius: 0;
            }

            /* Remove the jumbotron's default bottom margin */ 
            .jumbotron {
                background-color: #ffffff;
                margin-bottom: 0;
            }

            /* Add a gray background color and some padding to the footer */

        </style>

        <meta  name="viewport"  content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <meta name="robots" content="noindex">
        <meta name="Slurp" content="noindex">
    </head>
    <body>
        <!--      <div id="mySidenav" class="sidenav" >
          <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn" onclick="closeNav()">&times;</a>
          <a href="#">About</a>
          <a href="#">Services</a>
          <a href="#">Clients</a>
          <a href="#">Contact</a>
        </div>-->

        <div class="jumbotron"> <img  src="http://upscfever.com/upsc-fever/assets/images/logo.JPG" alt="LOGO - UPSC Fever" class="img-responsive"

                                      >
            <div class="container text-center">
                <p style="text-align: center;">INDIA'S #1 SITE FOR COMPETITIVE EXAM
                    PREPARATION</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
            <div class="container-fluid" >


                <div class="navbar-header"> <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle"

                                                    data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar"> <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span> <span class="icon-bar"></span> </button>
                </div>
                <div> 
                    <!--side navigator-->            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sm" onclick="openNav()" style="visibility: hidden;">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span> 
                    </button>
                    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">

                        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">

                            <li class="dropdown"> <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                                    UGC - NET <span class="caret"></span></a>

                                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                    <li> <a href="http://upscfever.com/upsc-fever/en/how-to-study/en-how2-ugc.html"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-education"></span>&nbsp;Studyplan</a>
                                    </li><li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
                                    <li> <a href="http://upscfever.com/upsc-fever/en/syllabus/en-syllabus-ugc.html"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-book"></span>&nbsp;Syllabus</a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
                                    <li class="dropdown-submenu"> <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">      Paper - I</a>

                                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">

                                            <li> <a  href="http://upscfever.com/upsc-fever/en/apti/apti-homepage.html"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-hourglass"></span>&nbsp;General Aptitude - Teaching Research</a>
                                            </li>
                                            <li> <a href="http://upscfever.com/upsc-fever/en/polity/en-polity-homepage.html">General Administration</a>
                                            </li>
                                            <li> <a href="http://upscfever.com/upsc-fever/en/environment/en-env-homepage.html">Environment</a>
                                            </li>
                                        </ul>     
                                    </li>       <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>    

                                    <li> <a href="http://upscfever.com/upsc-fever/en/history/en-history-homepage.html"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-header"></span>&nbsp;History</a>
                                    </li> <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>


                                    <li class="dropdown-submenu"> <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"> Indian Culture </a>
                                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">

                                            <li> <a href="http://upscfever.com/upsc-fever/en/culture/en-cul-homepage">Ancient Indian Culture</a>
                                            </li>
                                            <li> <a href="http://upscfever.com/upsc-fever/en/history/en-history-homepage.html"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-header"></span>&nbsp;Ancient History</a>
                                            </li> 
                                        </ul>    
                                    </li>             
                                    <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>

                                    <li> <a href="http://upscfever.com/upsc-fever/en/geog/geog-homepage.html"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-globe"></span>&nbsp;Geography</a>
                                    </li> 
                                    <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>

                                    <li> <a href="http://upscfever.com/upsc-fever/en/economy/economy-homepage.html"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-piggy-bank"></span>&nbsp;Economics</a>

                                    </li> <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>


                                    <li class="dropdown-submenu"> <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span>&nbsp; Public Administration
                                        </a>
                                        <ul class="dropdown-menu"> 

                                            <li>
                                                <a href="http://upscfever.com/upsc-fever/en/pubad/pubad-homepage.html">Indian Public Administration</a> 
                                            </li>  
                                            <li> <a href="http://upscfever.com/upsc-fever/en/polity/en-polity-homepage.html">Indian Polity</a>
                                            </li>   
                                        </ul>   
                                    </li>     <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>  


                                    <li class="dropdown-submenu"> <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"> Political Science
                                        </a>
                                        <ul class="dropdown-menu"> 
                                            <li>
                                                <a href="http://upscfever.com/upsc-fever/en/polity/en-polity-homepage.html">Political Theory</a>
                                            </li>      
                                            <li>
                                                <a href="http://upscfever.com/upsc-fever/en/pubad/pubad-homepage.html"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span>&nbsp;Indian Public Administration</a> 
                                            </li>  
                                        </ul>       
                                    </li>           


                                </ul>
                            </li>


                        </ul>
                    </div>

                    </div>
            </div>
        </nav>

    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a dropdown example

```js
    $(function(){
    $(".dropdown").hover(            
            function() {
                $('.dropdown-menu', this).stop( true, true ).fadeIn("fast");
                $(this).toggleClass('open');
                $('b', this).toggleClass("caret caret-up");                
            },
            function() {
                $('.dropdown-menu', this).stop( true, true ).fadeOut("fast");
                $(this).toggleClass('open');
                $('b', this).toggleClass("caret caret-up");                
            });
    });
```

```css
.caret-up {
    width: 0; 
    height: 0; 
    border-left: 4px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
    border-right: 4px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
    border-bottom: 4px solid;
    
    display: inline-block;
    margin-left: 2px;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown <b class="caret"></b></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
            <li class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
            <li class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
```